# React updating DOM in an unpredictable manner with setState and class names

Tags: javascript, css-animations, reactjs, requestanimationframe

I'm attempting to do an animation with React and CSS classes. I have created a [live demo](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh0V99WBvkJP0uACB1L), if you visit it and click the Start button you will see the text fade in and up one by one. This is the desired animation that I am after.

However, there seems to be issues of consistency when you hit Start multiple times and I cannot pinpoint why.

**The Issue:** Below is a recording of the issue, you can see the number 1 is not behaving as expected.

[live demo](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh0V99WBvkJP0uACB1L)

[image: React Animation]

**The process:** Clicking Start will cancel any previous requestAnimationFrame' and will reset the state to it's initial form. It then calls the *showSegments()* function with a clean state that has no classNames attached to it.

This function then maps through the state adding a `isActive` to each segment in the state. We then render out the dom with a map and apply the new state.

This should create a smooth segmented animation as each class gets dropped one by one. However when i test this in Chrome (Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)) and also on iOS, it is very inconsistent, sometimes it works perfectly, other times the first DOM element won't animate, it will just stay in up and visible it's completed transitioned state with "isActive".

I tried to replicate this issue in safari but it worked perfectly fine, I'm quite new to react so i am not sure if this is the best way to go about things, hopefully someone can offer some insight as to why this is behaving quite erratic!

```
/* MotionText.js */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import shortid from 'shortid';

class MotionText extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.showSegments = this.showSegments.bind(this);
    this.handleClickStart = this.handleClickStart.bind(this);
    this.handleClickStop = this.handleClickStop.bind(this);

    this.initialState = () => { return {
      curIndex: 0,
      textSegments: [
        ...'123456789123456789123456789123456789'
      ].map(segment => ({
        segment,
        id: shortid.generate(),
        className: null
      }))
    }};
    this.state = this.initialState();
  }

  handleClickStop() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafId);
  }

  handleClickStart(){
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafId);

    this.setState(this.initialState(), () => {
      this.rafId = requestAnimationFrame(this.showSegments);
    });
  }

  showSegments() {
    this.rafId = requestAnimationFrame(this.showSegments);

    const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    newState.textSegments[this.state.curIndex].className = 'isActive';

    this.setState(
      {
        ...newState,
        curIndex: this.state.curIndex + 1
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.curIndex >= this.state.textSegments.length) {
          cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafId);
        }
      }
    );

  }

  render(){
    const innerTree = this.state.textSegments.map((obj, key) => (
      <span key={obj.id} className={obj.className}>{obj.segment}</span>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickStart}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickStop}>Stop</button>
        <hr />
        <div className="MotionText">{innerTree}..</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default MotionText;
```

Thank you for your time, If there any questions please ask

[WebpackBin Demo](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Kh0V99WBvkJP0uACB1L)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the method to something like this works

```
render(){
    let d = new Date();
    const innerTree = this.state.textSegments.map((obj, key) => (
      <span key={d.getMilliseconds() + obj.id} className={obj.className}>{obj.segment}</span>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickStart}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleClickStop}>Stop</button>
        <hr />
        <div className="MotionText">{innerTree}..</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

How this helps is that, the key becomes different than previously assigned key to first span being rendered. Any way by which you can make the key different than previous will help you have this animation. Otherwise React will not render it again and hence you will never see this in animation.

Comment: Interesting, I tried the suggested code, but it has a strange effect of not showing the css animation at all, I wonder if this is because react is rendering the child with the class attached, rather than applying the class to the existing child... https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KhG9kZHz59GbdjKE5M2

Comment: It worked when I saved the code in the same window. Yes, you're right the animation got lost after this.

Comment: You can use the hack of adding a space before the numbers. Something like this ' 123456789123456789123456789123456789' with original code. Since only the first span remain there which doesn't animate this works.

Comment: haha, i actually tried that hack too, so far the best solution i've come up with is to put function into a setTimeout, the delay between setting state and calling the first requestAnimationFrame seems to give it enough time. 
I'm still not sure if this is the best way though ...

Comment: I've had a random lightbulb moment and I've worked out a solution and posted the answer, thanks for providing the insight to the React key, I couldn't have worked it out without this! The key - no pun intended - was to set a unique key upon generation/reset of the component, I used the initial state for this, putting it into the handler would also be sufficient.

Thanks for your help!